# Getting an error with the default tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

Below is the code that I have in my rails application.  I can't figure out why it's causing this error?  Any ideas where I should start looking?  I don't get where it's getting the DELETE FROM workloads call from.

The AccountsController & WorkloadsController are both empty.

### Test

```
require 'test_helper'

class AccountTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Replace this with your real tests.
  test "the truth" do
    assert true
  end
end
```

### Error

```
2) Error:
  test_the_truth(AccountTest):
  ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: TinyTds::Error: Invalid object name 'workloads'.: DELETE FROM [workloads]
```

### Account Model

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_defaults

  set_table_name "Account"
  set_primary_key "AccountID"

  private
  def set_defaults
    self.UCPIN = UUIDTools::UUID.timestamp_create.to_s
  end
end
```

### Workload Model

```
class Workload < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key "WorkloadID"
  set_table_name "Workload"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer... it has to do with fixtures needing to be redefined and reference.  Here's the site that gave me the answer.

http://www.missiondata.com/blog/systems-integration/80/rails-fixtures-with-models-using-set_table_name/

Answer (score 1):

It's behaving like you forgot to update your test schema.

`rake db:test:prepare`

If that doesn't work, look at `test_helper.rb` for any setup / teardown code, and post that if you get stuck.

Also, you're oddly using a table named `Workload` (singular / capitalized), implying a legacy db, but the error is referring to `workloads` (plural / lowercase). Check any config files you have for references to this table and make sure that it's spelled correctly.

Comment: Yeah I did a search through the entire code base and didn't find any references to "workloads".  Your assumption is correct it is a "legacy" database.  I'm connecting to a SQL Server 2008 database using TinyTDS.  I just noticed it's throwing an error before the test suite runs but that might be another question.  The error is.. /usr/local/bin/osql: illegal option -- E  Ran the rake db:test:prepare and trying to run the tests again, but it's taking it's sweet time...

Comment: This did not fix the problem.  There is not, nor should there be, a workloads table.  There is a Workload table and there should be.  I could not find any references to "workloads" in the code.